# How do I create a Vim function for toggling spelling and syntax by checking that spelling is on?

Tags: vim

At the moment, the following works by checking that the `spell` option is *off*:

```
function ToggleSpell()
    if &spell ==# "nospell"
        syntax off
        set spell
        echom "spelling is now on; syntax disabled"
    else
        set nospell
        syntax on
        echom "spelling is now off; syntax enabled"
    endif
endfunction
```

However, the following, which checks whether `spell` is *on*, doesn't seem to work, which is confusing me.

```
function! ToggleSpell()
    if &spell ==# "spell"
        set nospell
        syntax on
        echom "spelling was on ... turning off"
    else
        syntax off
        set spell
        echom "spelling was off ... turning on"
    endif
endfunction
```

When I do `:set spell?` on Vim when `spell` is on, I get `spell` with two spaces in front, which I suspect is part of the problem; however even if I modify the above to read `"  spell"` when checking the equality, the function doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

To toggle spell check you could use build in `!` feature

for example you could use one command to on and off spell check

`set spell!`

However `syntax on` doesn't have this feature, but you could achieve same result by

`if exists("g:syntax_on") | syntax off | else | syntax enable | endif`

Look at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html for details

Answer (score 2):

For Boolean options (`spell` / `nospell`), the output of `:set` is different from treating the option as a special variable (`&spell`). The latter evaluates to 0 / 1 (which represents Boolean values in Vim), so you shouldn't compare it to a String:

```
if &spell
    ...
```

It is an accident that the first version of your function works.  When comparing to a Number, both "spell" and "nospell" are converted to 0, so in both versions of your function, the condition is logically equivalent to

```
if &spell ==# 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether an option is set by testing equality with 1 (or 0 for unset):

```
if (&spell == 1)
```